# Behavior of LIMIT using JOIN clause

Tags: mysql, sql, join, query-optimization, limit

In mysql when you have 3 tables (huge amount of data ) are joined by JOIN clause, at the end of the SELECT you have a LIMIT clause, the sql engine makes the cartesian product of tables and after this applies the LIMIT, or exists any optimization made before?

I'm asking because the JOIN operation is a expensive operation if we are using big data volumes.

In this case is better do the JOIN and pull all data, or do the SELECT with LIMIT clause N times?

Comment: Mysql doesn't fetch more data than it is required to generate resultset. So if it is possible - it reads only `LIMIT` amount of rows

Comment: On the other hand, some things *may* prevent MySQL from terminating early -- e.g. an ORDER BY *can* force the entire RS to be materialized first because a LIMIT is a "view operation".

Comment: @pst: it's not that obvious - because `ORDER BY` may use indexes

Comment: @zerkms Good call. I added in the elusive "may" and "can". SQL database engines are quite smart.

Comment: see [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/limit-optimization.html) link on how MySQL optimizes the query depending on what else is present beside the join.

Comment: @jeshurun Nice link. I find the entry on ORDER BY slightly misleading though -- it doesn't imply a short short-circuit the JOIN, even if a short-circuit of the SORT can be performed.

Answer (score 1):

Short version: it depends on the query

Longer version: when you have a LIMIT clause, it assumes you have data ordered some way. If you do not explicitly specify the ORDER BY clause, you will see, that the execution of the query will stop as long as MySQL found the required number of rows.  If you have an ordering an it requires filesort, all data will be sorted in a temporary table and MySQL will output the first N rows you specified.

But if you forced the specific join order and index usage, MySQL will happiely short cirquit the execution.

Comment: Ok, this makes sense, because the index normally have a some kind of order, auto-increment, dates and so on. Therefore, if I use a WHERE clause and don't force the mysql engine to do a sort, the internal optimization can be done

Answer (score 0):

No, the limit feature is only a visual afterwards effect.

1/ the JOINS are calculated.

2/ the WHERE filters as well as the HAVING filters are processed

3/ the LIMIT reduces the number of returned results. The order are still kept, if you specified any ORDER BY clause.

Improve your joins to improve calculation overhead.

Comment: because to reduce overhead, you have to reduce rows scans. The limit feature doesn't prevent the scans since the parser still has to calculate everything to know what it has to "limit". Use WHERE clause to reduce overhead.

Comment: "still has to calculate everything to know what it has to "limit"" -- this is just wrong. mysql can return the rows as long as it got `LIMIT N` rows

Comment: no it is not, the where joins have to be calculated to know what are the rows to be returned. This is where the time is spent.

Comment: to return the resultset with `LIMIT 1` mysql shouldn't join whole billion-rows tables, it could just join 1 row from each table

Comment: @Sebas Unless there is something that requires the rows to be materialized to ensure the "correct N" are fetched (e.g. ORDER BY), there is no reason (or requirement) for SQL to do more work than is required to get the N rows (whichever N they happen to be). Of course, ORDER BY is most often used with any query so...

Comment: this is true about the order. But mysql has to prescan the employees to know that they belong to the company ID. ONCE this scan is processed, you can limit the results. If you didn't do so, you would just return a wrong result...

Comment: I think that if you have a sort operation into the query, you need join all dataset to after do the sorting and after this do the LIMIT, maybe this case is the worst case scenario that I can remenber

Comment: "I think that if you have a sort operation into the query, you need join all dataset" ---http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10711167/behavior-of-limit-using-join-clause#comment13909146_10711167